# Approximating $\ln(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, numerical-methods

Fix $\delta>0$ and $x>0$.  Suppose we have a sequence of numbers $x_n$ such that $\displaystyle |x_n-x|<\frac{1}{2^n}$. Is it possible to construct an $N$ so that $|\ln(x)-\ln(x_N)|<\delta$ by only using the information I know about $(x_n)$?

Comment: Yes. Because for some $0<y<x$, we have that as long as $x_n>y$, $$|\ln(x)-\ln(x_n)|<\frac1y\cdot |x-x_n|.$$ by MVT.